# Forbidden access but working with a refresh

Tags: php

I'm trying to access a streaming page but I get the error "Forbidden. You do not have permission to access this document."

However I can skip this message with F5/refresh and watch the video.

Is there any way to open this URL and do a refresh automatically? (using PHP)

I've tried something like this but it does not seem to work

```
header("Refresh:0; url=http://www.url.com");
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of treating the symptom, try to find the cause of your forbidden error in the logs.

Comment: To you control the streaming page?

Answer (score 0):

The forbidden access message is most likely coming from your web server configuration (apache?). The browser will stop there, and no document will be loaded from your server.

Since PHP is only interpreted after that, it will actually not get interpreted at all... you have no way to override this behavior in PHP alone, you need to fix your configuration on the server.

If you have a behavior that shows a 403 once every two load, chances are you have either a load balancer type of setup (loading one server or the other), or something that alternate between two configuration (for example issues in your domain name configuration, like the `ServerName` configuration).

In that case, if you add a `header("Refresh:0; url=http://www.url.com");` in your page, you will only get this worse, since the successful load will reload, and then get back to the forbidden message (403).

check your web server config and logs to find the issue.

Comment: Then I can't apply a refresh after a header?

Comment: no, you can't, your issue need to be fixed at the server configuration level

Comment: I'll have to refresh manually every time. Thank you for your help.

Comment: hum, what it stopping you from fixing your configuration?

Comment: Can you read my question again? I think I have not explained well.

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely the page is using HTTP REFERER restriction from it's own domain.

If you accessing the page by code, just added the referer condition on it.

In php you can use curl and add this line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'domain_url');
```

Comment: adding this line before the header is enough? curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://vercanalestv.com/');

Comment: @DavidBaez This link will help you with example how to use curl in php [curl-example](https://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/curl-example.htm)